# Authentication in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

The connection string for mongodb C# is as follows:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]hostname[:port][/[database][?options]]
```

Does the connection string itself implements the authentication?

I have seen the API of C# driver . It has the 4 methods for authentication:`check authentication, canAuthenticate,isAuthenticated and Authenticate , but they are internal . Please let me know about it? I am in great need of it.Thanks in advance..

Comment: Which MongoDB C# driver are you using? (there are about 4 of them right now in common usage)

Comment: Mongodb C# official driver for .net.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169064/mongodb-authentication-with-connection-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101506/mongodb-authentication

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can.

```
mongodb://[username:password@]hostname[:port][/[database][?options]]
```

And the official documentation for [CSharp Driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Connectionstrings) says:

> The username and password should only be present if you are using authentication on the MongoDB server. These credentials will be the default credentials for all databases. To authenticate against the admin database append "(admin)" to the username. If you are using different credentials with different databases pass the appropriate credentials to the GetDatabase method.

You can read the full documentation for connection strings on this [page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections).

Then if you want authenticate when you get a MongoDB database instance you can use

```
MongoServer.GetDatabase(String, MongoCredentials)
```

The documentation for that is [here](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.1/).

Comment: I am using Official driver for Mongodb C#.

Comment: Then . it means connection string itself implements authentication

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer with other links, try to look them.

Comment: Default credentials means only one pair of username and password for all databases

Comment: Yes for all the db running on the same MongoDB process. The connection string is one and you cannot specify different credentials for different DBs.

Comment: Ok, Then i have to hard-code username and password in this connection string.

Comment: and it also means all the authentication methods are invoked with this only one connection string

Comment: No I add to the answer how to connect with different credential for different DBs. SOrry, but at beginning I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Then what database option means in connection string

Comment: "These credentials will be the default credentials for all databases."

Comment: The database option means you can specify which database you are connecting to with your connection string. You can have multiple users in each database. If you create a user in the admin database they have admin rights and access to all databases.